# tener los mismos argumentos en varios metodos __init__ en python es posible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, poo, método

Estoy enviando los mismos argumentos a diferentes constructores y cuando necesito usar estos constructores solo me funciona uno eso me pasa con una función le hago diferentes llamados desde cada constructor y solo me responde a uno .Entonces queria saber si es posible usar los mismos argumentos para crear diferentes constructores(Metodos init)

Comment: Podrias explicar con mas detalle tu pregunta, te recomiendo leer [ask] y pasar el [tour]. Si no mejoras tu pregunta probablemente sea cerrada como poco clara

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo en la comunidad y estoy lidiando con este problema todo el dia mira lo que pasa. Es esto estoy  guardando en las variables nombre,dni,sexo  ect ,los datos ingresados por el usuario(test) y los estoy intentando enviar desde diferentes metodos __init__(tengo 5) a dos funciones  diferentes y la funcion solo responde a un metodo __init__

Comment: Estoy enviando los mismos argumentos a diferentes constructores y cuando necesito usar estos constructores solo me funciona uno eso me pasa con una función le hago diferentes llamados desde cada constructor y solo me responde a uno .Entonces  queria saber si es posible usar los mismos argumentos para crear diferentes constructores(Metodos __init__)

Comment: Te recomiendo explicarlo en tu pregunto, los comentarios son volatiles, ademas otro miembros de la comunidad le daran más importancia a tu pregunta que a los comentarios.

Comment: Listo amigo gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Te recomiendo proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Podrías colocar un poco de código para entender de mejor forma lo que deseas hacer?

Comment: Es perfectamente posible tener los mismos argumentos en varios métodos `__init__`, lo que no es posible es tener varios métodos `__init__` en una sola clase. Algo estás haciendo mal, pero no es posible saber qué si no pones tu código.